# i have a case like this, how to display data based on the number/id in the API

Tags: dart, fetch

I have a case where I want to filter data based on the semester the user chooses, for example, when selecting semester 2 it displays the data in semester 2.
but from BackEnd when you have to filter the data you have to add parameters as shown, how do you do that?
and when I want to filter by semester, I have to add a parameter to the endpoint, is there a solution?

[image]

> and this is when i call the API

```
  static Future<Map<String, DataKuliahModel>> getDataKuliah() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));

    Map<String, DataKuliahModel> finalResult = {};
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    final result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    result.forEach((key, value) {
      DataKuliahModel dataKuliah = DataKuliahModel.fromMap(value);
      finalResult.addAll({
        key: dataKuliah,
      });
    });
    return finalResult;
  }
```

> when it is displayed to the user

```
 FutureBuilder(
                  future: Services.getDataKuliah(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      DataKuliahModel selectedData =
                          snapshot.data!['$semester'] ?? DataKuliahModel();
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                                  spreadRadius: 1,
                                  blurRadius: 9,
                                  offset: const Offset(
                                      1, 2), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    selectedData.matakuliah,
                                    style: bold6,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ), ...
```

the result is like this in every card has the same value

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add smt to param, try this :

```
Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket?smt=${yourSmtValue}',
),
```

Comment: what if in my api I have a lot of data, say 9 data, means I have to call with 9 endpoints with different parameters?

Comment: if you want to filter by list of smt, then your backend need to let you pass list parameter

Comment: it can't, because it's part of the feature but from the backend it's like that and I have to follow.

Comment: If so, you will need to call 9 endpoints, can't do anything if your backend don't allow to do that

Comment: hmmm
maybe it will add more code, won't it be heavy when it's released later?

Comment: Yes, it will make your app bad performance, all I can tell you is try to communicate with backend team and suggest add another option for filter

Comment: is it possible to use listview.builder so the amount of data adjusts to what is in the API